# Mixing British and American spellings in writing

Tags: differences, grammaticality, pronunciation, american-english, british-english

I like *color* more than *colour*, but I like *favourite* more than *favorite*. For me it is better to write

> My **favourite color** is blue.

Is it wrong to mix British and American spellings in writing, and if so in which contexts shouldn't I?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I, too, like "color" more than "colour", but "favourite" more than "favorite". :)

Comment: I don't think it would be "wrong", but it would look horribly inconsistent.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Maybe because both of us are non-native speakers? At first contact,* "Colour"* sounded too posh, and *"Favorite"* sounded like it was missing a letter for a fluid pronunciation (and I feel tempted to write/say *"pronounciation"*...).

Comment: @Camilo: The fact that we're non-native speakers is important. More important is that I have never lived in any English-speaking country, therefore I don't have "my" English, be it American or British. But pronunciation of color/colour and favorite/favourite is the same in AmE and BrE, so I don't understand your point about pronunciation. And I would never spell pronunciation with `ou`, because it's just wrong :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Is it the same? I thought they were pronounced slightly different. Maybe it's because BrE sounds like "french-like english" to me in the sense that it's more refined (not to offend anyone, I don't know if french and british have a problem with each other...)

Comment: @Camilo: The French have a problem with everybody.

Comment: @Camilo: There is a difference between the pronunciations of color/colour though, but it concerns the final `r` rather than o/ou. The British do not normally pronounce the final r (unless the word is followed by another word starting with a vowel and these two are pronounced together quckly), but Americans do

Comment: @Camilo Martin: French and English [never](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_England) [had](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bouvines) [any](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years%27_War) [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_and_Indian_War) [whatsoever](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9V7zbWNznbs).

Comment: @Jay That's so harsh on them, Napoleon trying to take over Europe is water(loo) under the bridge.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Yeah, now that I check it sounds like "colah". Favo(u)rite sounds almost the same really, but both sound like as if they were the BrE version to me.

Comment: @nico Oh, I didn't knew about those. It seems I should think of England and France as the Europe version of China and Japan then :)

Comment: @Camilo Martin: and there is more! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-French_War

Comment: @nico on more recent news [Sarkozy did not greet Cameron](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2072061/EU-treaty-change-Nicolas-Sarkozy-snubs-David-Cameron-swife-body-swerve.html), the new was international even. I guess the whole Eurozone was pissed, but as I see, France is special. Please don't make another war, Fish and Chips and Champagne can live together.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Accents with and without the pronounced `r` (known as the *rhotic r*) are to be found in both Britain and America (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents#Distribution).  The dropped `u` is the result of an attempt to reform English spelling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_spelling_reform#19th_century).  I am not aware of any reason to think that the two are connected.

Comment: @Pitarou: I never intended to imply that they were connected. I must have misphrased. What I meant to say was that there *was* a difference between the BrE and AmE pronunciations of the word color, however you wish to spell it.

Comment: If the British were to adopt an American spelling or vice versa, I doubt that would change how they pronounced the word. I don't think accent is really tied to spelling, and that's basically what we're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no hard-and-fast rules against mixing American and British spellings, but as you suspected, there are contexts where you shouldn't do so.  For example, when writing for an American audience, avoid British spellings; and when writing for a British audience, avoid American spellings; but those cases aside, there should be no problem with mixing of spellings.

Comment: Are you implying that if a British person writes for an American audience, they should use American spelling and vice versa? :)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: well, it depends. If you are writing for an American newspaper, for instance, the editor will probably ask you to write in AE, even if you are British.

Comment: @nico: Yeah, probably. But don't you think that it's unfair that the stackexchange spellchecker deems the British spelling incorrect? It should be more open-minded IMO :)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Hmmmm... what is the SE spellchecker? Aren't you just seeing your browser's spellchecker (that you can turn to BE if you wish)?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Complicated corner case indeed. I doubt they'd bend to each other's spelling.

Comment: I guess the cases where somebody would write only for one or the other audience are somewhat rare today, except for news media or culture-specific blogs, and targeting single individuals.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Most writers do not have, or do not assume, an international audience. It's not that they intentionally try to write only for a British or American or Canadian audience, but that they write what they know, which is the local variant.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 So the "non-native" local variant counts?

Comment: @CamiloMartin: What do you mean? I'm in the chat room if you want to discuss this further

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Thanks for the invitation, but I have to go now. I was just considering the blog (in English) of a non-native English speaker could be in "custom English", since I sometimes like the way one is more than the other, arbitrarily. But I guess people don't even notice, so it's not much of an issue anyway.

Comment: I am an American. I've written two articles for an Australian magazine. On both occasions, they changed some of my spellings to British spellings. I told my friends it was my first foreign-language publication. :-) I suppose if a Brit was writing about British culture for an American audience, he might use British spellings for flavor (or flavour). But for general purposes, I would think you should use the language of the target audience to the extent you are able. Like, if you were writing for a French audience, wouldn't it be better to write in French?

Comment: @Jay I'm asking because written BrE and AmE are almost the same thing to me. Brazilian portuguese versus Portugal's, or Argentinian (*"Castilian"*) versus Spain's Spanish are so different, that really every English looks the same to me until they say something like "The bloke was so dodgy, mate" or one of the *o/ou* words.

Comment: @Camilo: If the question is, Is mixing the two a bad idea? I would say yes, because it's inconsistent. If the question is, Is this a glaring mistake that will make me look like a fool and subject me to ridicule and I will never be able to show my face in public again? I'd say no, it's not that big a deal. Readers won't say, "This moron can't speak English", they'll say, "Hmm, that's odd, I wonder why he did that", or maybe not even notice. I'd say the big warning is: Don't spell the same word two different ways in one document.

Comment: @Jay I understand what you say, and it makes sense not to mix the two variations in the same document. I'll try to watch myself on that, thank you for the input. I guess AmE is the most international variation.